# exiting out of a loop using getline when you encounter a newline character

Tags: c++

this might be the most basic of questions, but I have a problem exiting out of a loop using getline. Let's say a user enters these words using std::cin in the console:

```
/*
word
word_one
word_two

word_three
word_four
*/
```

And let' say we have defined an empty vector of vector of strings `vector< vector<string> >`. The desired `vector< vector<string> >` for this specific input must be: `< <word, word_one, word_two>, <word_three, word_four> >`.
My code for the following was:

```
int main(){
    vector< vector<string> > vv;
    vector<string> v;
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line)){
        if(line == "\n"){
            vv.push_back(v);
            break;
        }
        else{v.push_back(line);}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help? It feels like the if statement doesn't detect the "\n". It just goes on and on endlessly. (Also, don't worry about the includes and the namespaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are checking for "\n" where you have to check for "". This is because `getline` does not copy the "\n" character, so it will be an empty string.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector< vector<string> > vv;
    vector<string> v;
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line)){
        if(line == ""){
            cout<<line;
            vv.push_back(v);
            break;
        }
        else v.push_back(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `if` condition is never executed, because `getline` discards end of line character.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

An empty line would result in an empty string, not in a string contaning '\n'.